# Fatal warnings on Windows

Tags: mysql

While working between a Windows MySQL server and a Debian MySQL server, I noticed that warnings were fatal on Windows, but silently ignored on Debian. I'd like to make the warnings fatal on both servers while I'm doing development, but I wasn't able to find a setting that effected this behavior. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the sql_mode parameter in my.conf.  STRICT_ALL_TABLES is the value.  I guess it depends what you mean by "fatal".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at enabling strict mode in the /etc/my.ini file.